# what the difference of segment in ELF and memory

Tags: linux, memory, elf, segment

In ELf load use the conception of segment, and in memory management, logical address also use segment to search operator or instruction. So, is the segment same with each other? ELF files are load into memory to segment, and this segment is just the same segment used in memory menagement?

Answer (score 3):

Modern operating systems do not generally use *segmented memory* any more. Segmented memory is a relic of the DOS days of the 1980s and 1990s. While you can still choose "segments" for your memory operands, this is limited to the FS and GS "segments" which are reallly not segments but instead just offsets.

The memory model for most programs on most architectures is flat (not segmented).

*ELF segments* are nothing more than the specific chunks of data that get loaded into memory for a process to run. There will possibly be many, many segments if the process uses shared libraries, since each library will contain its own segments.

These two concepts of "segmented memory" and "ELF segments" are not really related, they just share a name.